# Sorting a tuple of dicts

Tags: python, sorting

I am new to Python and am curious if I am doing this correctly.  I have a tuple of dicts (from a database call):

```
companies = ( { 'companyid': 1, 'companyname': 'Company C' },
              { 'companyid': 2, 'companyname': 'Company A' },
              { 'companyid': 3, 'companyname': 'Company B' } )
```

I want to sort this on companyname.  Is there a more correct way than this to do it?

```
sortcompanies = list(companies)
sortcompanies.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(x['companyname'],y['companyname']))
```

Thanks for your criticism!

Comment: If it is possible for 2 companies to have the same name you could potentially have different final orderings based on the initial ordering. I don't know if this matters in your app.

Comment: Good point, that should never happen in my app, but it's something I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
import operator
...
sortcompanies.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("companyname"))
```

I think that's a matter of taste.

**EDIT**
I got `companyid` in stead of `companyname`. Corrected that error.

Comment: I like this better than what I was doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> companies = ( { 'companyid': 1, 'companyname': 'Company C' },
              { 'companyid': 2, 'companyname': 'Company A' },
              { 'companyid': 3, 'companyname': 'Company B' } )

>>> sorted(companies, key=lambda x: x['companyname'])
[{'companyname': 'Company A', 'companyid': 2}, {'companyname': 'Company B', 'companyid': 3}, {'companyname': 'Company C', 'companyid': 1}]
```

as you'll see when reading the [docs of `sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) first argument to the `sorted` might be any iterable, so you might not need even create the tuple.

Answer (score 2):

That's fine, but you might want to consider [sorting by keys](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sortingbykeys):

```
sortcompanies.sort(key=lambda x:x['companyname'])
```

instead. It's a little easier to read, and there will be fewer calls to `x['companyname']`.

@extraneon makes a good point about using `operator.itemgetter` as your key. That's pretty readable as well.